How to find a de-biased estimator with a ML component in my contaminated data problem?
I am trying to use the output of a machine learning model to estimate (using a maximum likelihood approach) a parameter in a distribution. The estimator I get has a bias which is much larger than the parameter value. I would like to find a debiased estimator using Neyman orthogonality / double machine learning approach (Chernozhukov et al., 2018), influence functions, or any related (or unrelated) approach. But it is not clear to me how to construct the debiased estimator in my case.
My estimation problem
I have "contaminated" data, modelled by a two-component mixture: most of the data comes from a probability distribution $P_0(x)$, but some of the data comes from a different distribution $P_1(x)$ (the "contamination"). I therefore assume that my data points are drawn iid from the distribution $$P(x) = (1-\theta) P_0(x) + \theta P_1(x).$$ My goal is to find the fraction of contaminated data $\theta$. The maximum likelihood estimator for $\theta$ is the solution of $$0 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i\frac{r(x_i)-1}{1+\hat{\theta}\bigl(r(x_i)-1\bigr)},$$ where $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are the datapoints, and $r(x) = \frac{P_1(x)}{P_0(x)}$.
I do not know the probability distributions $P_0(x), P_1(x)$ or their ratio $r(x)$ directly, but I do have another, labelled dataset $(\tilde{x}_i, y_i)$ of data points whose generating distribution is known: $y_i=0$ for points drawn from $P_0$ and $y_i=1$ for points drawn from $P_1$: $$Prob(\tilde{x}_i | y_i) = P_{y_i} (\tilde{x}_i)$$ (for simplicity, assume I have an equal number of $\tilde{x}_i$'s with $y=0$ and $y=1$).
Edit: To clarify, the fraction of data points with $y=0$ vs $y=1$ in this second dataset is not the same as the $\theta$ I'd like to estimate. The fraction of 0's and 1's in the second dataset is somewhat arbitrary, I am taking it to be 50% 0's and 50% 1's for simplicity. But other than this, the data in the second dataset is generated by the same process as the original dataset, i.e., 0's are generated by $P_0$ and 1's by $P_1$.
I therefore attempt to estimate $\theta$ in two steps:

Train a ML classifier $f(x)$ on the labelled dataset to estimate $Prob(y=1|x)$, and thus obtain an estimate the probability ratio as: $\hat{r}(x) = \frac{f(x)}{1-f(x)}$.

Plug this $\hat{r}$ in the MLE equation, yielding $$0 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i\frac{\hat{r}(x_i)-1}{1+\hat{\theta}\bigl(\hat{r}(x_i)-1\bigr)},$$ and solve for $\hat{\theta}$.


Note that the dataset used for the MLE estimation (step 2) is different from, and independent of, the data used to train the ML model (step 1).
My questions
$\hat{r}$ is a biased estimator, as discussed, e.g., in the double machine learning literature (see link above). I therefore get a biased estimator for $\theta$. In my case I am interested in values of $\theta$ much smaller than this bias. I would therefore like to find a debiased estimator for $\theta$. But I am confused about how to apply the double machine learning approach or influence functions to my case.
What would be a Neyman-orthogonal MLE equation in my case? How can I use the information I have to find a debiased estimator of the contamination fraction $\theta$?
Edit:
I believe my description above of the problem setting remains somewhat unclear, so let me try to clarify. I have two distinct datasets:

$\mathcal{D}_1 = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$, where each $x_i \in \mathcal{X}$ is a feature vector (the space of features $\mathcal{X}$ can be thought of as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^k$ for some $k$). These are drawn iid from the distribution $P(x) = (1-\theta) P_0(x) + \theta P_1(x)$.

$\mathcal{D}_2 = \{(\tilde{x}_1, y_1), (\tilde{x}_2, y_2), \ldots, (\tilde{x}_m, y_m)\}$, where each $(\tilde{x}_i, y_i) \in \mathcal{X}\times \{0,1\}$ is a pair of feature vector + label. These are drawn iid from the distribution $P(\tilde{x}, y) = \frac{1}{2} P_y(\tilde{x})$.


Importantly, the same two probability distributions $P_0(x)$ and $P_1(x)$ are used in the generation of the two datasets. In the Double Machine Learning literature such functions are often referred to as "high dimensional nuisance parameters". Had I known them, the MLE equation written above would have given me a good estimator for $\theta$. I want to use the second dataset to learn as much as I can about $P_0$ and $P_1$, then use this information in the estimation of $\theta$ in the first dataset. The approach I'm currently pursuing is to estimate the ratio $r(x) = P_1(x)/P_0(x)$ from the second dataset, and plug it in the MLE equation. But this results in a biased estimator for $\theta$, and I'm looking for ways to debias this estimator.
Another edit: I thought of a motivating example that will hopefully further clarify my question (loosely inspired by a Seinfeld episode. I know nothing about cigars): say I get a huge shipment of Cuban cigars, and I suspect some of them are in fact Dominican. I wish to estimate which proportion of the shipment is of Dominican origin, and to test whether this proportion is significantly different from 0. I have no idea how to tell cigars apart, so what I do is buy M Cuban cigars and M Dominican cigars, measure a bunch of features for each cigar (weight, length, color, etc.), and train a machine-learning classifier on this labeled set of 2M datapoints. From this model I can estimate the likelihood ratio $P_1(x)/P_0(x)$ for every new datapoint. I now want to use the information I learned from the classifier to estimate the fraction of Cuban cigars in the original shipment. My problem is that naively plugging in my estimated likelihood ratio into the MLE equation leads to a biased estimator. I would like to detect fractions of Cuban cigars that are smaller than the bias I am getting, so am looking for ways to de-bias the estimator.


Is the process that generated $x$ for the labeled dataset the same as the one that generated the unlabeled dataset?  2. How large are your sample sizes?



For the sake of discussion, let's assume the two processes are indeed the same (in fact, there's might be some selection bias in the datapoints that got labelled, but this adds extra complications, which at this point I'm ignoring). 2. The labelled ML training set is about 10^6 datapoints, and the unlabelled dataset for estimation is about 10^9 datapoints.


It seems to me that if you have $10^6$ labeled data points, you can estimate $\theta$ quite accurately by the proportion of $y$ values equal to one.  In your formula for $P(x)$,  $\theta$ is not a function of $x$, so that should work well.

Oh, sorry, I should have clarified: I have two sub-datasets of labelled points, one generated by the distribution $P_0(x)$ (with $y=0$) and the other generated by the distribution $P_1(x)$ (with $y=1$). Together they comprise of the training dataset. The relative sizes of these is somewhat arbitrary, and not related to the fraction $\theta$ which I would like to estimate. So when I say that training and estimation datasets have the same data generating process, I really mean that they are the same except for the proportion of 0's and 1's. I hope this is clearer now.

Ah, thanks, that clarified it!  Might want to put that directly into the question, just to help readers like me out.

What distributions do $x$ follow in the two scenarios?

In my case $P_0(x)$ and $P_1(x)$ do not belong to any known parametric family. $x$ is a high dimensional vector of features, some of which are categorical, others are numerical. Does this answer your question, @jbowman?

Looks like a typical latent-class model. You can search for documentation, papers and books in the R package gmnl for this model.

Thanks for the suggestion, @DrJerryTAO! This is indeed a latent-class / mixture model, where I wish to estimate the mixture proportions. I was not able to find in the literature (including the gmnl package literature) references that address my problem, probably due to my lack of familiarity with this vast literature. If you could point me to specific references where this type of problem is discussed I would really appreciate it.

Under your stated assumption, your parameter is non-identifiable
You have said that the values of $y_i$ are not sampled using the proportion $\theta$ that is the subject of your inference.  The problem that results from this is that the parameter $\theta$ should not appear in your likelihood function, so your stated MLE is invalid.  (You appear to have derived it under the assumption that $\mathbb{P}(Y_i=1) = \theta$, contra your stated assumption.)
If you are indeed correct in your statement that $\mathbb{P}(Y_i=1)$ is not determined by $\theta$ then this parameter is non-identifiable in your model, and so you have no basis to estimate it.  Contrarily, if $\mathbb{P}(Y_i=1) = \theta$ (as implicitly assumed in the derivation of your MLE) then you can estimate $\theta$ in an unbiased way using the sample mean $\bar{y} = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i / n$.

Thanks for the answer. I believe my question lacked clarity, I added more details at the end of the question, hopefully now it is clearer.
I have two distinct datasets. In the first one, a proportion of $\theta$ is drawn from $P_1$ and the rest from $P_0$, but the datapoints are unlabelled. The MLE equation refers to this dataset. The second dataset is indeed labelled, but points there are not drawn using the proportion $\theta$. The combined information from both datasets should make $\theta$ indentifiable, but it cannot be trivially inferred from labels.

If the second dataset with both predictors and binary responses has a mixture of two data generating processes, you can estimate the mixing probability from a typical latent-class multinomial regression model. You can search for documentation, papers and books in the R package gmnl for this model, such as Sarrias, M., & Daziano, R. (2017). Multinomial logit models with continuous and discrete individual heterogeneity in R: The gmnl package. Journal of Statistical Software, 79, 1–46. https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v079.i02. Since your response is binary, the latent-class binary regression basically estimate three sets of coefficients:

One set describes the log odds of $y_i$ based on $x_i$ if each observation comes from Group A.
Another set describes the log odds of $y_i$ based on $x_i$ if each observation comes from Group B, which can be different from those above.
A third set describes the log odds of whether each observation comes from Group A or Group B. This part can have the intercept only, giving a constant mixing probability $theta$ throughout the whole sample.

The latent-class binary regression model uses your "second" dataset only. With the fitted model, you can predict the latent class (as well as $y_i = 1$) probability as a constant or based on $x_i$ in the "first" dataset.
If $y_i$ is observable only in a subset of the population, but one intends to estimate patterns for the entire population, a sample selection issue emerges. For example, whether a loan request is approved or declined can be observed only if a client submits a request. Yet most clients may not generate any requests, and therefore their loan request result is never observed. An economist may nevertheless want to know the loan approval probability is for all customers to profile their customer base. See Toomet, O., & Henningsen, A. (2008). Sample selection models in R: Package sampleSelection. Journal of Statistical Software, 27(7). https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v027.i07. Whether or not $y_i$ is observable, $x_i$ is always observed. In this situation, a sample selection model will estimate two sets of coefficients:

One set describes a binary regression (typically a probit model) of whether $y_i$ is observable based on $x_i$. This part typically needs at least one extra predictor (i.e., instrument variable) than the following part.
Within the subset where $y_i$ is observed, another set describes the relationship between observed $y_i$ and $x_i$.

The classical sample-selection model has a continuous $y_i$, but you can find packages that are designed for binary $y_i$. This model is closely related to instrument variable and causal inference. It uses both "first" and "second" datasets to fit the first set of coefficients and uses the "second" dataset only to fit the second set of coefficients.
I am not sure if any machine learning algorithms have been developed for latent-class or sample-selection models, but machine learning algorithms typically only fit the outcome variable and do not provide intermediate results such as the probability of latent class or sample selection that do not constitute the outcome directly.

New Answer
You indicated that the second dataset has the response $y_i$ in the way that $y_i = 0$ if the data come from Group A, and $y_i = 1$ if from Group B. Then we do not have either latent class or sample selection. The "classes" are known in the second dataset. We simply need to predict them in the first dataset. This problem is a standard binary regression. The process involves

Fit a binary regression of $y_i$ on $x_i$ using the second dataset. This can be logit, probit, or some machine learning classification problems.
Use the model estimated from the second dataset to predict $y_i = 1$ based on $x_i$ to get $p_i$ for each observation $i$ in the first dataset.
Take the average of the above predicted probabilities across the first dataset, $\theta = \bar{p} = p_i/N$.

You will find the R and Python package marginaleffects useful to complete Step 2 and 3. Its function avg_predictions() does both steps together. You simply need to supply the first dataset to predict for in the newdata= argument. This procedure is exactly how metropolitan planning organizations forecast future travel model split. The average of predicted probabilities among individuals becomes the aggregate proportion. The individual predicted probabilities can be also useful and informative. I am not familiar with the "double machine learning" concept. I doubt that if anything beyond a binary regression or classification is necessary.
You plan to "test whether this proportion is significantly different from 0". I do not think the reference point $\bar{p} = 0$ is very useful. At this boundary point, none of possible samples should have any positive case under the null hypothesis. Most statistical tests work poorly on parameter boundaries. See Hypothesis testing on proportions if $H_0: p = 0$ and How to test if a single proportion is significantly different from zero. Instead, you can test something like $H_0: \bar{p} \leq .03$ and claim something like "our sample is at least 99.7% pure". With a significance level $\alpha = .05$, you will build a 90% confidence interval of the average predicted probability. If its lower limit is greater than $.03$, reject $H_0$. marginaleffects::avg_predictions() automatically provides standard errors and confidence intervals. For a standard logistic regression, it provides $z = \bar{p}/\mathrm{se}(\bar{p})$ statistic, analogous to the basic z test of proportions. The corresponding confidence interval is symmetrical based on the standard normal distribution. For a super larger sample size and estimates in the regular range, this might be okay. But for limited sample size and estimates on their boundaries, this z test may not behave well. You can instead transform both $\bar{p}$ and $\mathrm{se}(\bar{p})$ estimated by avg_predictions() onto the logit scale to linearize them, using the simple one-variable delta method so that $x = \ln{\bar{p}/(1-\bar{p})}$ and $\mathrm{se}(x) = x^{\prime}(\bar{p}) \mathrm{se}(\bar{p}) = \frac{1}{\bar{p}(1-\bar{p})}\mathrm{se}(\bar{p})$. Then calculate the 90% confidence interval first for $x$, which is $x \pm 1.645 \mathrm{se}(x)$, and then for $\bar{p}$ after inverse transformation. For example, the lower confidence limit of $\bar{p}$ will be $\frac{\exp{[x - 1.645 \mathrm{se}(x)]}}{1 + \exp{[x - 1.645 \mathrm{se}(x)]}}$.

Thanks for the detailed answer! I like your description of my problem. Here are some comments I have.

I agree that the problem has similarities with causal inference. The use of ML models to infer model parameters (not precisely intermediate results like latent-class probabilities, but similar in spirit) is, to my understanding, precisely what the double machine learning literature I referenced is doing. This is why I believe it is a promising approach in my case, and I am hoping someone here might shed light on it.



Your second prescription (use the labelled dataset to learn the relationship between x and y, and use both datasets to learn something about the population at large) is similar to what I'm trying to do. I have the extra simplification that the probability of being labelled introduces no selection bias except of changing the mixture proportions.


Adopting your loan application example, in my case individuals apply for a loan at random, in the following funny way: M individuals are chosen to apply uniformly at random out of all the individuals who would've been approved for a loan, and similarly M are chosen uniformly at random out of all the individuals who would've been denied. This doesn't really make sense for loan applications, but does make sense in the applications I have in mind. This leads to the probability distributions written (in the edit) at the end of my question. Under this assumption, there is no sample selection issue.


I am not sure why you say my goal does not appear logically feasible. Continuing with your loan example, from the labeled dataset I can learn the criteria to be granted or denied a loan [these are the distributions $P_0(x)$ and $P_1(x)$]. Once I have this information, I use it with the unlabeled dataset to estimate which fraction of the population would be granted a loan had they applied. This again might not make too much sense in the context of loan applications, but is sensible in my case. I've added to the question a motivating example, hopefully it clarifies my intentions.


I could not understand well the relationship between the first and second datasets based on the symbols. With the toy example, I updated my answer. Your problem is a standard application of binary regression and prediction.

Thanks very much for the new detailed answer! I still believe it does not address my original question. Yes, I can use a classifier to estimate $\bar{p}$ as you suggest, and even obtain confidence intervals as you detailed. It is not clear to me how to relate $\bar{p}$ to the quantity that interests me: the proportion parameter$\theta$. More importantly, your suggestion does not deal with the bias issue that I am asking about, namely, your $\bar{p}$ will be biased when estimated by modern ML methods, and I am looking for ways to debias the estimator.

Having said this, I will award your answer the bounty as it is about to expire and no better answers were provided. I nonetheless do hope that a full answer will yet be provided.

$\theta = \bar{p}$. Generalized linear models (GLM) by maximum likelihood give consistent estimates of coefficients. There is a bias but the bias shrinks with a larger sample size. The bias in estimated probabilities are ambiguous, because it is a nonlinear transformation of all coefficient estimates. To avoid inconsistent estimates, specify the binary regression properly (e.g., include functions, smooth curves, and interactions of predictors). I do not know statistical properties of machine learning algorithms. It is not clear what type of bias you were talking about.

Thanks! As discussed in the paper I referred to in the question (Chernozhukov et al., 2018, see for example Figure 1), regularization methods employed by ML models such as Lasso, random forests, gradient boosting, neural networks trade variance for bias, and estimators based on outputs of such models tend to be biased. I am not sure I understand why $\bar{p}=\theta$. Say $\theta =0$. I wouldn't expect the output of the model to always be $p_i = 0$, right? A pretty confident model might easily output $p_i$'s around 0.1.

To clarify my last comment, and going back to the example of Cuban vs Dominican cigars: perhaps there's varied spectrum of cigars from each country, and it is impossible to know with high certainty the origin of each and every cigar. In such a case, even the best model might often predict probabilities close to 0.5. So even if all my cigars are Cuban, it could very well be the case that $\bar{p}$ would be 0.1 or 0.2 or 0.3 (where $p_i$ is the predicted probability that cigar $i$ is Dominican). Why should I expect this number to estimate $\theta$?
